# Wordpress, условие в цикле

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте. Есть цикл `while`, который выводит новости с кратким содержанием. Внутри этого цикла засунут цикл `foreach`, который проверяет к какой категории относится новость и на основе этого присваивает посту картинку. Проблема: если у поста 2 категории то выводится 2 картинки, что не нужно. Как правильно прописать условие, что бы категория с нужным ид не учитывалась? Надеюсь понятно изложил.
Код:

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
    echo '<img src="http://сайт.ru/catimg/' . $category->cat_ID . '.png" alt="' . $category->cat_name . '" />'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так?

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
    if($id_hashcode!=get_the_ID()){
        echo '<img src="http://сайт.ru/catimg/' . $category->cat_ID . '.png" alt="' . $category->cat_name . '" />';
    $id_hashcode = get_the_ID();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, заработало! :)
Только вот надо ли вписать ид рубрики в get_the_ID()? А  то и так и так работает.
И подскажите пожалуйста что такое id_hashcode.

Comment: Оставте всё как есть) id_hashcode - это временная переменная, которая содержит предыдущий id в цикле.

P.S. Не забываем отмечать ответ как правильный(галочка такая слева от ответа)